# give different volume tags while creating ec2 instance from custom AMI

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ami

I am creating an ec2-instance with the custom AMI that has 2 volumes. I want to give separate names/tags to both of the volumes like

vol-lab-cam-web-aue1-sda1 to the root volume and 
vol-lab-cam-web-aue1-sdb to the other volume using terraform.

I can only see a volume_tags option in terraform docs. Is there any workaround for doing this ??
My sample code is below

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
ami           = "ami-0e6f18d5546ceec3d"
instance_type = "t2.micro"
volume_tags = {
  Name = "vol-lab-cam-web01-aue1a-sda1"
  }

tags = {
  Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

Following is the Screenshot of what i get using this
[sdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq9XR.jpg)

[sda1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCkJD.jpg)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to tag the volumes with the device ID?

Comment: Yes because these AMIs have multiple volumes and there are more than 100 ec2 instances. Its hard to find which one is root or not.

Comment: Why do you need to identify the root/non root volumes from outside the instance?

Comment: Because at times we need to increase volume size that are non root, we dont want to go in the situation by stopping or detaching root volume from the servers.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No. Instead I have to create a lambda function that calls ssm document to get the volume mount point and tag to respective volumes

Answer (score 1):

Since `volume_tags` gets applied uniformly to all devices created at launch time, don't use it for device-specific values. Instead, use the [`aws_ebs_volume`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_volume.html) resource to create the `sdb` volume and the [`aws_volume_attachment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/volume_attachment.html) resource to attach it to the instance.

In the `aws_ebs_volume` code, you can enter "vol-lab-cam-web-aue1-sdb" for the *Name* value.

Comment: That doesn't help when the AMI has 2 volumes

Comment: Exactly, that's a solution to create a new volume and attach it to the ec2-instance. @ydaetskcoR is right

Comment: Gotchya. I didn't glean that from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Like KLH says if you create 2 volumes in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "drivea" {
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone}"
  size              = 40

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "driveb" {
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone}"
  size              = 40

  tags = {
    Name = "WhaleTail"
  }
}
```

Like thus and then attach them to your instance:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebsa" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.drivea.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebsb" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdi"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.driveb.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
}
```

You will have 2 disks attached to your instance with different tags.
Then if you look in your AWS console you will see the different volumes with different tags.

Comment: My custom AMI has 2 volumes, I am not creating new volumes to attach with ec2 instances.